# Counting number of "NaN" (not zeros or blanks) in csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nan

Is it possible to have Python count the number of 'NaN' (as string/text) in a csv file? Tried using pandas' `read_csv`, but some columns which have blanks are read as NaN also. The only working method I know is to use excel find 'NaN' as values.

Anyone knows of other methods? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `pd.read_csv` but you will need two parameters: `na_values` and `keep_default_na`.

1. `na_values`:

> Additional strings to recognize as NA/NaN. If dict passed, specific
>   per-column NA values. By default the following values are interpreted
>   as NaN: ‘’, ‘#N/A’, ‘#N/A N/A’, ‘#NA’, ‘-1.#IND’, ‘-1.#QNAN’, ‘-NaN’,
>   ‘-nan’, ‘1.#IND’, ‘1.#QNAN’, ‘N/A’, ‘NA’, ‘NULL’, ‘NaN’, ‘nan’`.

2. `keep_default_na`:

> If na_values are specified and `keep_default_na` is False **the default**
>   **NaN values are overridden**, otherwise they’re appended to.

So in your case:

```
pd.read_csv('path/to/file.csv', na_values='NaN', keep_default_na=False)
```

If you want to be a bit more "liberal" then you might want something like `na_values=['nan', 'NaN']`--the point is these will be interpreted very strictly.

An example--say you have the following CSV file with 1 literal NaN and two blanks:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('input/sample.csv', na_values='NaN', keep_default_na=False)
print(np.count_nonzero(df.isnull().values))
# 1
```

Comment: You can quicken up the summation with `np.count_nonzero(df.isnull().values)`

Comment: @piRSquared Thanks--deliberate decision that DataFrames can't operate on both axes at once?  (In the way that NumPy defaults to without specifying an axis.)

Comment: Yes!  Key differentiator between the two. *Usually* pandas columns are distinct things that are linked with a common index.  Think of a `pd.DataFrame` as a series of series.  Short answer: Yes! deliberate decision.

Answer (score 1):

**Setup**
Consider a csv file named `tst.csv` that looks like this:

```
h1,h2,h3
NaN,1,
2,3,NaN
5,6,9
NaN,1,
2,3,NaN
5,6,9
```

**Solution**
Use `open` and `str.count`

```
with open('tst.csv') as f:
    c = f.read().count('NaN')

print(c)

4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.isna().sum()
```

it will list the number of NaNs per column